# judgmental and propositional statements in homotopy type theory

Tags: logic, type-theory, homotopy-type-theory

In homotopy type theory one has to distinguish between judgmental and propositional statements, eg
in case of $a: A$ ("$a$ has type $A$") and equalities $a =_p b, a=_A b$. That is, are a judgemental and propositional "$x$ has type $X$" statement, und there are also a judgmental and propositional equality.

I not know how can I evolve an intuition on how to distinguish them. What I read is that generally a statement is propositional if it is "internal" in the theory, while judgmental means that the
statement is "external" in the sense that it is "about" the theory itself and therefore cannot be derived (or say better "constructed") in the theory. On the other hand what does it concretely mean that a statment is "internal" to the theory?

If we try to think about it in case of our "toy examples" $a: A$ and the two equalities, that's sounds strange. How can $a: A$ be simultaneously a internal and external statement? How it can be an internal and external statement (that is "within" the theory and "about")? The same question arises on judgmental and propositional equalities.

Is there a conventional way how one should distinguish between them? Sorry if the question is too broad and indifferent, I think it's hard to find a key to approach these two crucial concepts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mark's answer is good, but let me add just a bit more.

Zeroth, this distinction belongs to all dependent type theories and has nothing particular to do with HoTT.

First, in the particular context of HoTT, I don't like the word "propositional" here because in HoTT a special role is played by the types with at most one element, which we call "(mere) propositions", whereas the so-called "propositional equality" need not be a proposition in this sense.  So I prefer "typal equality".

Secondly, there is no typal version of $a:A$.  It is only and always a judgment.  This is in contrast to ZFC, where set-membership $a\in A$ is only and always a proposition.  The corresponding judgment in ZFC is "$a$ is a set", which is trivial since every object in ZFC is a set.  In type theory there are different types of things that are classified by their types: the elements of a function-type $A\to B$ are functions, the elements of a product-type $A\times B$ are pairs, and so on.  So the judgment $a:A$ indicates what type of thing $a$ is, by virtue of having been given a valid definition (or by assumption), before we even start to draw conclusions about it.

Thirdly, a nice analogy (at least) for the difference between definitional/judgmental equality and typal/propositional equality (suggested by Steve Awodey) is that between equality of [sense and reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sense_and_reference).  Judgmental equality is equality of sense: two *expressions* are judgmentally equal if they can be seen to be the same by simple syntactic manipulation of their definitions.  In particular, it is not a "mathematical" concept because it is a statement about the syntactic form of a description of an object rather than the object itself.  Typal equality is equality of reference: two *objects*, which may be *referred to* by expressions, are in fact the same object.

Comment: The sense and reference analogy looks great, thank you! So in summary judgemental equality can be seen as something "obvious" for the system in the sense that it can be checked by computer as "kind of checking-autopilot" (hope the analogy is not too bad), while propositional equality is something that is "hidden" internally in the theory and to uncover it we have to "spend proper intellectual effort"? (ie it's something that contained in the theory itself and it cannot be for example something which is "injected" as external input like eg a definition)

Comment: Is my attempt to rephrase this analogy halfway correctly?

Comment: Yes, that's more or less right.  Like most things in this subject it's more complicated than any simple explanation can capture, because there are type theories (e.g. extensional type theory with equality reflection) for which the judgmental equality *can't* be checked by a computer, and others (like, ironically, the type theory of the HoTT Book, where the judgmental equality of MLTT is supplemented by computation rules for point-constructors of HITs) where there's "clearly" an algorithm to do it but no one (to my knowledge) has actually proven that the algorithm works.

Comment: Moreover, "obvious" doesn't always mean "easy", as for instance there is a well-known term in cubical type theory ("Brunerie's number") which we can prove to be typally equal to 2, and which therefore (by canonicity) must be judgmentally equal to 2, but running the algorithm that checks equality on that term seems to blow up in complexity and memory usage beyond what's feasible to actually evaluate.

Comment: But at a high level, I would say that your rephrasing is correct.

Comment: Yes right, the word "obvious" wasnt well choosen there.
Trying to take the pathologies you mentioned above into
account, one may at least say, that the point is that
the "nature" of proofs of judgmental and propositional 
equalities is fundamentally different.
Maybe one should sloppy say that proofs of 
judgmental properties is that kind of effort that a lazy
mathematician wishes to shift on computer/ proof assistent (as 
you remarked in practice this not always work well,
but in the sense of a "motivation"),

Comment: while proving
of propositional equalities is that kind of work that stays to
be done by the lazy mathematician oneself :)?

Comment: Sure.  Although of course there are also exceptionally lazy mathematicians who try to get the automated theorem provers to prove things like typal equalities for them...

Comment: But the message is that such "approaches" are naturally not in the "sprit" of HoTT, or to say it more precisely these approaches are not consistent with the distinction of jugdmental und prepositional equalities in sense of HoTT? Or is the issue at this point also a bit more complicated?

Comment: No, I wouldn't say that.  There's nothing wrong with automated theorem proving.  The distinction between judgmental and typal equalities is a mathematical one that has a certain precise meaning.  These informal glosses can help to understand it, but I'm just pointing out that they only go so far and can mislead if you take them too seriously -- ultimately the true "meaning" of the distinction is in the mathematics.

Comment: I think here is the core of my 
understanding problem on this issue.
How the distinction between them is pure 
mathematically formulated?

Comment: For example, if we say we have $a:A, b:A$,
and we want to talk about $a=_A b$ and
$a \equiv_A b$. What says at this point the
pure mathematical distinction at that point?

Up to now if we have no additional information
one can mathematically only say that
$a=_A b$ and $a \equiv_A b$ are different "somehow in their 
nature" in sence of the complete framework, and thats
all we need to know mathematically? Is this the "mathematical distinction" which you mentioned
above, or is there also in formal sense more?

Comment: If yes, then lets look closer. In typal case one can always
as far I think write down without running in troubles the type
$a =_A b$ (of course it could happen that it
has or has not an inhabitant), but formally it 
is always alowed so far? And to find out if there
is an inahabitant in $a =_A b$ or to use the assumption
that there is an inhabitant there, are exactly that
kind of reasonings which are called "inside the theory"?
Is what wrote correct so far?

Comment: Now we come to judgmental equality $a \equiv_A b$.
Can it always simply be written down without running 
into troubles or should we in this case in order to have
the "permission" to do it or not have additional informations
about $a:A$ and $b:B$. The point why I asking this maybe
silly question, is that in the HoTT book I somewhere read
a formulation like "... therefore it not make sense to 
write $a \equiv_A b$ ..."

Comment: So this lead me to conjecture that in contrast to typal case,
which can always be written simply down (if Im not wrong above), the case $a \equiv_A b$ might be a bit more 
problematic. Or am I wrong? On the other hand example isnt it always 
possible to introduce $a \equiv_A b$ as a definition or 
should one here be also more careful?

Comment: Just like you can always write down $a=_A b$ as a type, but it might not be provable, you can always write down $a\equiv_A b$ as a judgment, but it might not be derivable.

Comment: I see. So when you say "derive" you refer to deductive 
system consisting of a system rules which provide
exactly the framework/toolbox to 
work with judgments. And thats seems to be the only one 
rigid way that is allowed to "touch or work" with judgments
when we do HoTT, right?

Comment: Besides, you wrote in a comment above that in order
not to despair to much on these informal ways providing an "intuition" to 
distinguish typal und judgmental equalities which 
unfortunately not capture the complete picture its
better to use the formal correct pure mathematical
distinction between judgmental and typal 
equalities which provides exactly the
precise meaning. Could you explain how this
distinction is formally correctly imposed? Do you refering to some specific lines in the HoTT book? Up to now I found there only the "semiformal" explanations misleading me exactly in the

Comment: way you wrote above

Comment: That's about right; the deductive system is the way we interact with judgments by deriving them.  Formally it is analogous to the machinery of first-order logic that we use to prove statements in set theory.  In particular we cannot formally "dis-derive" a judgment, just as we cannot formally "dis-prove" a proposition in first-order logic -- in FOL we can approximately disprove a statement by proving its negation, but a judgment does not have a negation.

Comment: The most formal description of the judgmental apparatus of type theory in the HoTT Book is in Appendix A, but generally we tried to eschew excessive formality.  Depending on your background, you might find my [unfinished notes on categorical logic](http://mikeshulman.github.io/catlog/catlog.pdf) to be helpful, or my paper [the logic of space](https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.03007).

Comment: Thank you very much for explanations and references, I will deal with them soon.

Comment: About your analogy between jugdments in HoTT and 
propositions in FOL Im still quite confused. 
You wrote that we cannot formally "dis-derive" a judgment, 
just as we cannot formally "dis-prove" a proposition in 
first-order logic. The second part confuses me. Then you also wrote 
that in FOL we can still disprove a statement by proving its 
negation, but a judgment does not have a negation. But in set-theoretic 
FOL we "not know" concept of judgments, or do we?

Comment: Here Im a bit confused. If we forget at this point the 
concept of judgments 
from HoTT und only focus on the naive FOL world: What 
is for you the difference between a proposition and 
statement? I thought up to now that they are used 
synonymously. I also assume that everywhere where you 
talk about FOL all reasonings happens in naive set-theoretic 
framework, right?

Comment: According to my rudimetarary knowledge of FOL a proposition 
is a formula (en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-formed_formula) which 
has no free variables. And in FOL a proposition can be either 
true or false; it must be one or the other, and it cannot be 
both. For example it can be disproved if we prove its negation. 
So what you mean precisely when you say that "we cannot formally 
"dis-prove" a proposition in first-order logic"? On the other 
hand a statement can be disproved as you said, 
so what is the difference between statement and proposition?

Comment: "Statement" is not a word that's commonly used in formal theories of deduction and logic, but by it I meant "formula" or "proposition".  (The presence or absence of free variables is irrelevant, since logical deduction happens in nonempty contexts as well.)  I did not mean to make any distinction by happening to use different words "propostiion" and "statement" for the same thing in two instances.

Comment: Just as in set theory we don't usually talk about "types" because there is only one type (the sets), in FOL we don't usually talk about judgments because there is only one judgment, namely "P is true" for some formula P.  There is (in usual presentations of FOL) no judgment "P is false".  This is what I meant by "we cannot dis-prove a proposition"; if we want to "disprove" P, instead of deriving an imaginary judgment such as "P is false" we have to derive the judgment "not-P is true".

Comment: My point was that our ability to do this depends on the presence of a "negation" operation on the *formulas*, which are the objects that the judgments are *about*.  In the absence of such an operation, but without changing the judgments, there would be no notion of "disproof".

Comment: The idea that in FOL a proposition "must be either true or false" is, first of all, specific to classical logic and not intrinsic to the notion of FOL.  Even in that context its meaning is slightly subtle.  It is true semantically, in the sense that in any "model" of a first-order theory every proposition is assigned either to true or to false.  It is also true that we can always derive the judgment "(P or not-P) is true" (depending on the presentation of classical FOL this may just be an axiom).  But it is not true that we can always derive either "P is true" or "not-P is true".

Comment: maybe I see what you mean now. I think that thats exactly
how the HoTT book at the end of page 17 tried to 
visualize the concept of a general deductive system
consisting of judgments and rules:
If we imagine a deductive 
system as a graph where knots/vertices are judgments
and edges are rules.

Comment: so lets try to apply it to case of FOL where as you 
said the only judgments are "proposition P is true".
And the only "operations" which we can perform there is 
to start at one knot (say judgment J1="prop Q ist true")
and our goal is - if we want to check that we can
derive from this another judgment, let call 
it "prop P ist true" - to check if J2="Q ist true" is 
connected to "P is true" by a finite chain of 
edges (=rules). So if I understand your
reasonings above correctly and try to project
these into the "language of this graph model" then 
then the question of proving

Comment: something is 
to find just a chain of edges connecting to judgements
and nothing more. So the issue on why formally "dis-proving something" fails, is because
the derivative system *just a priori does not gave a
meaning to "not J"*, thats what you mean by that
*" in FOL a proposition "must be either true or false" 
is not intrinsic to the notion of FOL,"* thats the point, right?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 2):

There are two kinds of judgements in Homotopy Type Theory.

The first is a "typing judgement". This is a judgement of the form $a : A$.

The second is "judgemental equality". This is a judgement of the form $a \equiv_A b$.

Propositions in homotopy type theory are represented as types. This means that whenever $a : A$ and $b : A$, $a =_A b$ is a type.

There is no type $a \equiv_A b$.

All reasoning done within homotopy type theory is done using propositions-as-types. For example, let's say that I wanted to show that $a = b$ implies $f(a) = f(b)$.

The type theory statement of this would be $a =_A b \to f(a) =_B f(b)$ (assuming that $f : A \to B$). This is actually a type - the type of all functions which take an element of $a =_A b$ and return an element of $f(a) =_B f(b)$.

Because $a \equiv_A b$ is not a type, there is no type $a \equiv_A b \to f(a) \equiv_B f(b)$.

This suggests that all reasoning within homotopy type theory should be done using propositional equality because the propositions involving equality cannot even be stated using only judgemental equality.

Another example: let's say we want to show that for all $n : \mathbb{N}$, $n + 0 = n$. To even phrase this problem at all, we would have to phrase it as $\prod\limits_{n : \mathbb{N}} n + 0 =_{\mathbb{N}} n$. It is not even possible to state the problem without using propositional equality.

Judgemental equalities are useful for the purposes of definitional computations. For example, part of the defition of $+$ is that $0 + n = n$ for all $n$. In this case, because this is a definitional equality, we actually have $0 + n \equiv_{\mathbb{N}} n$ for every term $n : \mathbb{N}$. So a lot of definitional simplifications are done using judgemental equality.

On the other hand, it is not within the definition of $+$ that $n + 0 = n$. Therefore, it cannot be shown that $n + 0 \equiv_{\mathbb{N}} 0$ for every term $n : \mathbb{N}$.

So a better way to think about judgemental equality is definitional equality. When one thing is defined to be equal to another, the equality is judgemental. Otherwise, the equality is propositional.

Comment: So the meaning of "internal" here is that all the internal
statments (=propositions) "live independently in their
own cosmos like a closed system strictly decoupled from external "things" 
(which are for example definitions which we may regarded as "external inputs")? 
That is to say that something is a "internal feature or result of the theory
itself" is equivalent to say that it can be concluded by 
"playing/ reasoning" which involves only propositions, nothing more,
right?

Comment: @user7391733 That seems roughly right. But it's a bit vague. I think the best way to understand what's going on with judgemental vs propositional equality is to just do some proofs in HoTT (or, perhaps better yet, in an automated proof assistant like Coq which is based on Martin-Lof type theory).

Comment: Maybe another attempt to rephrase & understand it: A propositional 
statement  is something about "one could think" in the
sense that the "thinking" means here playing with 
propositions with the aim to prove of disprove it; that is
one asks if the considered propositional statment is true
or not and tries to find it out. While a judgmental statment
is a statement with intrinsical property that it is meaningless
to think about it if it is true or not (like in case of
a definition). Maybe this is a better intuition?

Comment: So say informally an judgmental statement is a statement of the type about which one could say that "it is a priori meaningless to search for an answer within the theory of it", because by it's nature the theory not "contains" an answer, maybe so?

Comment: A proposition has a truth value – it is true or it is false; a judgement does not – it is justified or it is unjustified. Propositions are semantic; judgements are syntactic. Propositions belong to the model; judgements belong to the deductive system. etc.

Comment: @ZhenLin Mostly correct. The only quibble is that propositions don't have to be either true or false since HoTT uses constructive logic.

Comment: @MarkSaving Well, HoTT doesn't have to use constructive logic.  People usually take that to be the default since a lot of people working on HoTT care about constructivity and categorical models, and a lot of things can be done constructively.  But it's still HoTT if you assume excluded middle.

Comment: @MikeShulman True. I perhaps should have said "HoTT does not necessarily use classical logic" - that would have been more precise. By the way, I am thoroughly enjoying working through your arxiv paper on material/structural set theory and stack semantics, and it's quite neat to interact with you personally.